# Is this an alright method for buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

I'm practicing with buttons in Unity and I'm trying to figure out how I can assign different methods to a button without using the OnClick thing in the inspector so I came up with this.

```
public class UIButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var buttons = FindObjectsOfType<Button>(); //I should probably have this outside of this method
        foreach (Button button in buttons)
        {
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonPressed(button));
        }
    }

    void ButtonPressed(Button button)
    {
        switch (button.name)
        {
            case "MMPlayButton": //The main menu play button
                Debug.Log("Play button pressed");
                break;
            case "PlayButton": 
                Debug.Log("Play button pressed");
                break;
            case "SettingsButton":
                Debug.Log("Settings button pressed");
                break;
            case "QuitButton":
                Debug.Log("Quit button pressed");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.LogWarning("Button doesn't have a case: " + button.name); 
                //could do some kind of pop up message saying the button pressed isn't available or something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know this can work, however, I'd imagine this is a horrible way to do things because it's using the name so if I were to change the name or make a typo it breaks, or an issue I did encounter was if buttons have the same name, and if I add more buttons I'd have to add more cases and then it would probably turn out to be a giant mess.

I could be wrong though and maybe this is an alright idea, but I doubt it so looking for some help with this.

Comment: As far as performance goes, switch statements involving strings like this end up as giant if/else if statements, and they certainly are fragile from a maintenance point of view like you suggest. Definitely much worse than a method being directly invoked by AddListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this by using inheritance.  Create a base class for all of your buttons to use, ie. `UIButtonBase` that has the `OnButtonPressed` virtual method.  Then create specific buttons that inherit this base class and override the `OnButtonPressed` method.

**Base Class**

```
public class UIButtonBase: MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        var button = GetComponent<Button>();
        if (button)
        {
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnButtonPressed());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(name + " does not have a Button component!");
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual void OnButtonPressed()
    {
        Debug.Log("UIButtonBase::OnButtonPressed()");
    }
}
```

**Specific implementation of a button**

```
public class SettingsButton : UIButtonBase
{
    protected override void OnButtonPressed()
    {
        Debug.Log("SettingsButton::OnButtonPressed()");

        // If you want the base functionality as well, add..
        //
        base.OnButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

For setup, create a button and add this script to it.  You may need to change the `GetComponent` in `Awake` (UIButtonBase) to `GetComponentInParent` or `GetComponentInChildren`, depending on your gameobjects hierarchy.  You could also expose the Button component in the UIButtonBase script and use that reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't be a good answer but if I were you, I would make different files for different buttons. Like SettingButton.cs, PlayButton.cs etc.

This approach will not add a huge amount of burden to your code but as the functionalities of your buttons increase, this approach will greatly help to keep your code organized.